# How to correctly constrain a clock network with lots of mux branches?

Tags: clock, vlsi, timing-analysis, constraints, sdc

Let me simplify a common clock network structure used in my company:

Firstly, there're multiple true clock sources (PLLs, external input, or RC OSCs).

Right at the beginning when these sources are "born", they are MUXed, and we call this generated clock "system clock".

Then this system clock travels through a lot of clock divider modules. All these `DIV`s have the same internal structure: the output clock is selected between the input clock and a divided input clock (using D-FFs). Each `DIV` outputs a clock which clocks certain digital logic, and can drive the next `DIV`.

```
                                  DIV(1)
             +-----+    +----------------------+
clk src 1 -->|     |    |                      |
clk src 2 -->| MUX |--------+--------->+---+   |
clk src N -->|     |    |   |  +--+    |MUX|-------+--------------------------> block 1
             +-----+    |   +--|FF|--->+---+   |   |  +------+
                        |      +--+            |   +->|DIV(2)|---+------------> block 2
                        +----------------------+      +------+   |  +------+
                                                                 +->|DIV(N)|--> block N
                                                                    +------+
```

Then, how can I constrain this clock structure correctly and neatly?

Can I `create` a "system clock" at the first `MUX` output? Or should I let all the sources pass?

And how am I supposed to handle all these `DIV`s? The number of SDC CLOCKs will grow rapidly if I write SDC like this:

(suppose there's only one SDC CLOCK at the entry of DIV(1))

---

generate a clock after DIV(1)'s FF  ---->  so, block 1 get 2 SDC CLOCKs

---

generate a clock after DIV(2)'s FF from DIV(1)'s bypass path

generate a clock after DIV(2)'s FF from DIV(1)'s FF path  ----> so, block 2 get 4 SDC CLOCKs

---

so on.

Or, how can I improve this structure?

Comment: What is its function?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 different part of our system needs different clock frequency. But basically they have a relation of divide-by-2/divide-by-4/etc. The whole system is still synchronous.

Comment: Is that an ASIC design, an FPGA, or a CPLD (i.e. can you even derive a clock in logic without penalty, or would you fare better with generating enables)?

Comment: @SimonRichter It's ASIC. I have to define too many generated clocks at each FF's Q (for each possible master clock, define a generated clock).

Answer (score 1):

Quite tricky and a bit complex. What I would have done is (SDC Contraints):

1. Constraint clocks *src_1* to *src_N* using:

   `create_clock -name clk_1 -period <> [get_ports src_1]`

   *Note:* I assumed clock sources as top-level ports.
2. The above clocks automatically propagate through `Mux` to different end points in the design, so you may not need another clock constaint at the `Mux` output. But there will be clock paths which are contradictory and will not actually exist on design physically (Eg: *src_1* to *src_2* path can't exist because Mux will forward only one of the clocks) and yet gets evaluated by the timing analyser. To avoid that, use:

   `set_clock_groups -exclusive -group {get_clocks clk_1} -group {get_clocks clk_2} .... -group {get_clocks clk_N}`
3. For `DIV_1` clock divider, you should create a generated clock at the output of the last flip-flop in the chain or at the input to the `Mux1` inside it. The source clock for this generated clock will be the `Mux` output:

   `create_generated_clock -divide_by X -source [get_clocks[get_pins Mux/Mux_output]] -name clk_DIV1 [get_registers/get_cells clk_DIV1_flop]`
4. Repeats steps 2-3 for the rest.

---

*Note:*

*If this is on FPGA, you have to use dedicated clock-multiplexers, and not an RTL one, and avoid RTL clock dividers. This is to avoid routing of clock through FPGA fabric (poor skew, slew, jitter, latencies ...)*

Comment: It's ASIC. May I ask how do I specify the master clock in step 3 if the `-source` is the mux output? Actually the problem I'm facing is that if I define each clock exactly obeying the SDC rules (for each possible source clocks, generate a clock at the FF output), it will result in too many clocks.

Comment: You have to find the name of that instance and it's pin/port from netlist/RTL and derive clock using [get_clocks[get_pins[Mux/output]]. 'Mux' is the instance. If there are too many, you should find a way like script or something to auto generate or maybe there are specific looping constructs you can use within SDC.

Comment: Still confused. If generating and propagating many clocks is the only correct way to constrain this structure, then I'll either use script or redesign clkgen module.

Comment: That's right. You have no other choice. Because each one of these are different clocks. So you have to define them yourself to convey the information to the simulator. I have seen people using scripts in situations like these. @Light

Comment: This is because the timing analyser is not aware that your blocks are clock dividers, and neither it's aware of what factor you will divide it, and neither it's aware of how to handle the muxed clock. So you have to convey this information.